# WiFi drivers suddenly disappear Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04

Upon installation of Ubuntu 18.04, I installed the WiFi drivers as per standard procedure from the "Software and Updates" interface and everything was working fine. All of a sudden, without any system update or anything of that sort I was unable to connect to the WiFi because of `No WiFi adapter found` (despite me having installed it already).

The WiFi is correctly switched on, everything seems to be in place: for instance

```
$ nmcli radio wifi
enabled
```

and

```
$ ifconfig
enp3s0f2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 30:65:ec:07:51:a7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx048705ea6058: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.224  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2a02:8109:9200:23cc:306f:334c:5f32:6f5f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:8109:9200:23cc:c419:c684:822a:e929  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::83a1:2bfa:d8b2:7313  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:87:05:ea:60:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4290  bytes 2741868 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4149  bytes 564683 (564.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 873  bytes 70852 (70.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 873  bytes 70852 (70.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

EDIT: Additional information resulting from `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info`, as suggested in the comment below, can be found [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2gP54M2d8d/)

What can be the cause of the problem? How come, all of a sudden, the drivers seem not to be recognised anymore?

Comment: You need to provide more info, not just ifconfig output: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that re-installing the drivers works, for some reasons:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: It didn't work. I 'm still having trouble about disappeared wifi adapter in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.